# WCF callback to multiple clients correctly

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, duplex

So I have a wcf service that is controlling a bunch of measurement instruments and a few cameras. I made it so the service callbacks the connected clients every time the camera readies its bitmap. The code all functions correctly however I am afraid of stability issues later on because I essentially just have a list of contracts that is updated with each new connection, and I remove old ones by catching exceptions... and I don't feel too confident in that.

Anyway here is the code:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class ServiceCamera : IServiceCamera
{
    private static Dictionary<string,ICamera> Cameras = new Dictionary<string, ICamera>();
    static List<IMyContractCallback> cblist = new List<IMyContractCallback>();
    private void camera_ImageReady(object sender, Bitmap bitmap2)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < cblist.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cblist[i] != null)
                {
                    cblist[i].ServiceImageReady(bitmap2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cblist.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    public void Connect()
    {
        callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyContractCallback>();
        cblist.Add(OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyContractCallback>());
        ICamera camera;
        if (Cameras.ContainsKey(OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress.Uri.Segments.Last()))
        {
            camera = Cameras[OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress.Uri.Segments.Last()];
            if (!camera.IsConnected)
            {
                camera.ImageReady -= camera_ImageReady;
                camera.Connect();
                camera.ImageReady += camera_ImageReady;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            camera = (ICamera)InstrumentLoader.Factory.GetNamed(OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress.Uri.Segments.Last());
            Cameras.Add(OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress.Uri.Segments.Last(), camera);
            camera.ImageReady -= camera_ImageReady;
            camera.Connect();
            camera.ImageReady += camera_ImageReady;
        }
    }
}

public interface IMyContractCallback
{        
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ServiceImageReady(Bitmap bitmap);        
}
```

This is my first experience with a duplex wcf and feel that I can improve a lot on it. I have a feeling that most of what I am trying could probably be done by making changes to the InstanceContextMode.

Comment: It would be much easier to do so via SignalR by keeping long live connections. Using WCF for such tasks is too complex.

Comment: SignalIR looks interesting and I'll take a look. However in our current case a lot of what we are doing is through tcp communication and later http. It looks like Signal IR is mainly http. Also the service runs surprisingly well and supports multiple clients.

Comment: SignalR on .NET Core will eliminate the HTTP limitation to support other protocols. Do you often suffer timeout related issues in your WCF based solution? That's the typical trigger to migrate.

Comment: How easy will it be to use my existing .net 4.7 libraries with it? And will the HTTP limitation be eliminated if communicating with a .net 4.7 client? Also we don't have many issues with the clients as this is all done on our local network. I'm looking into it now and the groups look like they can be very useful.